# Repository Pattern, Observer Pattern - practical example

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, observer-pattern

I'm trying to be a better C# programmer and use best-practice design patterns.

Can someone please explain how best to approach the following real-world example in code, using the repository pattern and the observer pattern?

I have a system which contains companies. Companies have departments and employees. Also, each company pays a subscription which limits the number of departments / employees they can create.  You can't have a company without at least one department and that department should have one employee.

When I create a repository for companies - in the "create company" code, should I also create the first department and the first employee, or should I leave the repositories separate, or is it better to have a simple single call for "Create company" that does it all?

In the "Create department" code - I want to ensure the company can't create more departments that they have paid for.  I'm guessing the right thing here is the observer pattern - notify the "Subscription" code that the company is attempting to create a new department and then stop it if it's going to go over the limit - but I haven't got a clue where to start!

All help very much appreciated.

Comment: This question is off-topic here but you might check the helpcenter and/or meta of programmers.stackexchange.com to see if this question is welcome there.

Comment: Agree with @Maarten. While you could use observer to effectively make the checking asynchronous, you've demonstrated no reason to do so, so it would be hard to justify the extra complexity, compared to say if (LicenceCheck.CanAddCompany(CustomerID) ...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to implement *business validations* by using the observer pattern. That is the wrong approach IMHO.

Since the observer pattern is about objects being notified of certain events, and those objects are implementing certain behaviour, it is not a match for *business objects* containing data which are being persisted by the repository pattern.

What you are describing is simple validation of business objects. You are trying to make sure that your data is only being persisted when certain checks are passed. In your repository (or somewhere in your domain/business layer if you have one) take your data, validate it, and persist it.